# FreeMarker do is have a option to assing value to variable from static html text

Tags: java, html, spring, templates, freemarker

I search all over the net I can't figured out Is have a chance to assign value to variable from the static html from list.

```
<#list users as user>
   <#assign userId = //the user id value here// ><p>${user.id} </p>
</#list>
```

The user id value must be from the `<p>` tag

**EDIT**

```
<tbody>
<#assign count = 1>
<#list departmentsList as department>
<tr>
  <td>${count}</td>
  <td>${department.name}</td>
  <td class="text-right">
    <div class="dropdown dropdown-action">
      <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit_department"><i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5"></i>Edit</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_department"><i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i> Delete</a>
      <#assign employeeId = ${employee.id}>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<#assign count ++>
</#list>
</tbody>
```

`${employeeId}` return last element from list.I need selected.

This is the table I use I do a loop form list I need to click of anchor to take the current department ID I try to use href, but it's not working since `data-target="#edit_department` use JavaScript and just don't work. How can I get the ID for selected department when press EDIT or DELETE to use the variable in the HTML which open after press the anchor and is in another div

**HTML DIV WITH ACTION FORM**

```
  <div id="edit_department" class="modal custom-modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Department</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <form  action="departments/update/${departmentId}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Department Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
          <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="submit-section">
          <button class="btn btn-primary submit-btn">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your table can have many departments each with its own id but you have only one `<div id="edit_department">` that your JavaScript code opens. Therefore your JavaScript code must read out the id of the department that needs to be edited and insert into the form within the `<div id="edit_department">` (and for editing you probably also want to set the current department name as default for the name).

Comment: Not related to the question, but note that you don't need to maintain your own `count` variable. Instead you can just use `<td>${department?counter}</td>`.

Comment: Yes, I was not familiar with this when I post the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with *from static html text*: the user id value that is written into the `<p>` tag is created dynamically (because you use `${user.id}`).

Of course you can use that same value within an `assign` directive:

```
<#assgin userId="${user.id}">
```

or (even better and shorter):

```
<#assgin userId=user.id>
```

See the [FreeMarker documenation](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_assign.html) for more information.

---

In your more specific example you probably want to have two `data-` attributes in your links (one for the operation and another one for the department id):

```
<tbody>
<#assign count = 1>
<#list departmentsList as department>
<tr>
  <td>${count}</td>
  <td>${department.name}</td>
  <td class="text-right">
    <div class="dropdown dropdown-action">
      <a href="#" class="action-icon dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="material-icons">more_vert</i></a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-operation="#edit_department" data-target="${department.id}"><i class="fa fa-pencil m-r-5"></i>Edit</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-operation="#delete_department" data-target="${department.id}"><i class="fa fa-trash-o m-r-5"></i> Delete</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<#assign count ++>
</#list>
</tbody>
```

And then your JavaScript code can access the operation as well as the id of the department to work with.

Comment: Yes I know, but the ${user.id} is in the loop and assign the last element from the list.I need the value which is in current table index. That's why I need the static text. For this I see in documentation is not possible

Comment: `<#assign userId=user.id>` - no need for the `"${}"` around it.

Comment: @mikebrucks I don't understand. What do you mean by the "current table index"? Maybe you want `user?index` or `user?counter`? See https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html#ref_builtin_index

Comment: I need to assign the ID of the object user to the variable, but when I do <#assign userId = ${user.id}> I get the last ID of the element in the list because is n the loop and save the last value

Comment: @mikebrucks if you have for example 10 users your template fragment produces 10 `<p>` tags with 10 different user ids in them. If you only need one of them then your question is very unclear and you need to include more code to show which of the user ids you need.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I update the question with more code

Comment: Is not working, it's not opening the window I will add and the div with the edit_deartment HTML